# How to make the functions of necessary database operations?

Tags: python, database, postgresql

How do I convert this code into proper function, means create table should be in seperate function, making connection should be seperate and inserting , viewing records too,  I am trying but getting error, if anybody can help me:

```
import psycopg2
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('dataframe.csv')

#  creating connection
conn = psycopg2.connect(database = "postgres",
                        user = "postgres",
                        password = "12345",
                        host = "127.0.0.1",
                        port = "5432")

print("Opened database successfully")

# Creating table stockmarketforecasting
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE STOCK_MARKET_FORECASTING
      (date           VARCHAR(30)       NOT NULL,
       open           float        NOT NULL,
       high           float        NOT NULL,
       low            float        NOT NULL,
       close          float        NOT NULL);''')
print("Table created successfully")

# Inserting records in database
for i in range(0 ,len(df)):
    values = (df['date'][i], df['open'][i], df['high'][i], df['low'][i], df['close'][i])
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO STOCK_MARKET_FORECASTING (date, open, high, low, close) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                values)

conn.commit()
print("Records created successfully")

# View the records
cur.execute("SELECT * from STOCK_MARKET_FORECASTING")
rows = cur.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print(row)
print("Operation done successfully")
conn.close()
```

Below code is which I am trying to convert into functions but getting error, Please tell me that what thing I am doing wrong.

**My code:**

```
import psycopg2
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('2_months_dataframe.csv')

#  creating connection
def create_connection():
    conn = psycopg2.connect(database = "postgres",
                            user = "postgres",
                            password = "12345",
                            host = "127.0.0.1",
                            port = "5432")
    print("Opened database successfully")
    return conn
conn = create_connection()

# Creating table stockmarketforecasting
def create_table(conn):
    conn = create_connection()
    cur = conn.cursor(conn)
    cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE STOCK_MARKET_FORECASTING
          (date           VARCHAR(30)       NOT NULL,
           open           float        NOT NULL,
           high           float        NOT NULL,
           low            float        NOT NULL,
           close          float        NOT NULL);''')
    print("Table created successfully")
    
    conn.commit()
    return conn, cur
conn, cur = create_table(conn)

# Inserting records in database
def insering_records(df, conn, cur):
    for i in range(0 ,len(df)):
        values = (df['date'][i], df['open'][i], df['high'][i], df['low'][i], df['close'][i])
        cur.execute
        ("INSERT INTO STOCK_MARKET_FORECASTING (date, open, high, low, close) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                    values)

    conn.commit()
    print("Records created successfully")
    return cur, conn
conn, cur = insering_records(df, conn, cur)

# View the records
def viewing_records(conn, cur):
    cur.execute("SELECT * from STOCK_MARKET_FORECASTING")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        print(row)
    print("Operation done successfully")
    return rows
    conn.close()  
rows = viewing_records(conn, cur)
```

Comment: is this a `pandas` or `postgresql` question? please remove the unnecessary tags

Answer (score 0):

I've made some corrections to your code, and it should work in this form. Let me know if you have any issues.

```
import psycopg2 as ps
import pandas as pd

# Here you can put your database credentials
DB_HOST = ''
DB_NAME = ''
DB_USER = ''
DB_PASS = ''

df = pd.read_csv('dataframe.csv')

# Here you create a temporary connection, that closes automatically when the code stops
with ps.connect(dbname=DB_NAME, user=DB_USER, password=DB_PASS, host=DB_HOST) as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        print("Opened database successfully")

        # Creating table stockmarketforecasting
        cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE STOCK_MARKET_FORECASTING
            (date           VARCHAR(30)       NOT NULL,
            open           float        NOT NULL,
            high           float        NOT NULL,
            low            float        NOT NULL,
            close          float        NOT NULL);''')
        print("Table created successfully")

        # Inserting records in database
        for i in range(0 ,len(df)):
            values = (df['date'][i], df['open'][i], df['high'][i], df['low'][i], df['close'][i])
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO STOCK_MARKET_FORECASTING (date, open, high, low, close) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                        values)

        conn.commit()    
        print("Records created successfully")

        # View the records
        cur.execute("SELECT * from STOCK_MARKET_FORECASTING")
        rows = cur.fetchall()
        for row in rows:
            print(row)
        print("Operation done successfully")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @mss051, Your answer is not as my expectations because I addressed in question that to write the code in functions, each database operation should be in separate function